What are the ways to define optionally binary / ternary operators with shared keywords (e.g. for ... else) without unintended ambiguities?
Suppose I would add an optional else branch to the for statement, with whatever semantics. Or even harder, that I would allow the programmer to define custom ternary operators, with the third operand being optional.
How to design it so that it would not surprise programmers get used to similar constructs, say if ... else?
For example, if the following code is translated to the language, else should always pair with if. And there should be a different way to make it pair with for.
if(condition)
    for(;;)
        body;
else
    fallback;

This is easy in Python, Lisp or endif-style grammars. But I want to know if there is a reasonable way for every (non-esoteric) type of grammar. Specifically, I want it to work in a language with the basic grammar as close to C as possible.

Isn't this basically the same as the problem of multiple else if statements? And the solution is probably the same: by default, else pairs with the most recent if or for, and you use braces to override this default.

What about this is specific to having two separate statement kinds? It looks like you would have the same problem when just nesting two if statements.

Yes, if(a) if(b) c; else d; is already ambiguous if you don't require braces around the branches.

The point is the normal way of resolving ambiguity would confuse programmers unaware of the existence of for ... else.

This is known as the Dangling else problem

Note how even for an if without an else there is some ambiguity:
if expression1 expression2;

Because where does expression1 end and expression2 begin? In C this ambiguity is resolved by requiring expression1 to be wrapped in parentheses. Rust does this the opposite way: expression2 must be wrapped in curly braces. The latter actually solves the ambiguity of the else clause. Consider this bad example in C:
if (foo)
   if (bar)
      baz();
else
   quux();

If you wrote something similar in Rust:
if foo {
    if bar {
        baz();
} else {
    quux();
}

It would be a syntax error, as there is a closing curly brace missing, and where you will put it will determine if the else-clause belongs to the inner or the outer if.

A simple solution is to require an end keyword. Then you can parse your expression easily, depending on the first keyword (if/for/etc) and optional arguments are covered because the end makes it distinct.
Then you can distinct between
if(condition)
    for(;;)
        body
    end
else
    fallback
end

and
if(condition)
    for(;;)
        body
    else
      fallback
    end
end

just by the different placement of the end keywords (thanks to @ChrisDodd for pointing this out).
Another example:
if x + if y then 1 else 2 end = 5 then for y in array do x+=y end end


Actually, if the end is always required (in a for statement as well as an if), it does solve the problem -- the placement of the end for the for determines whether the else binds to the for (else before end) or the if (else after then end for the for).

@ChrisDodd oh, you are right! I missed that, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

This is known as the dangling else problem and it can be formulated and resolved at different levels.
Level 1 is the syntactic level. We can avoid the problem syntactically; this is usually done by adding brackets of some kind. For instance, ALGOL 68 has
IF ...
THEN
  ...
FI

An ELSE part is optional.
Because the THEN and FI are required, the ...s may contain arbitrary sequences of statements, and arbitrary nested occurrences of this construct, without producing ambiguity.
ALGOL 68's ternary "operator" is simply IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... FI, i.e. the same construct (ALGOL 68 allows statements wherever expressions are allowed, and vice versa).
More languages use this approach, e.g. the Bourne shell.
An alternative is to require brackets around all sequences of statements/expressions. E.g. always require the brackets in if ( ... ) { ... }. Many languages do this.
You're asking: what if we don't. Many languages don't; for instance, C and Pascal.
This is level 2: our syntax doesn't protect us, so we need a defense at the semantic level.
The standard defense: precedence rules. We really don't care what the grammar for a * b + c * d looks like, but we disambiguate it using the precedence rule that * binds more strongly than +.
Similarly, we have precedence rules to disambiguate a ? b ? c : d, and if (a) b; c, and if (a) if (b) c else d, and whatever else. Users will need to look them up and apply them correctly every time, and if they're smart they will put in extra brackets anyway, but it is up to them, and as a consequence, lots of errors will still be made, because the language invites them.
Some programmers prefer this approach anyway. Not everyone is happy with Lisp syntax.
So now, I hear you ask, let's take for granted that our language is like this, and that programmers are like this, is there still something we can do? A level 3 defense?
Yes, there is: we can make our compiler (or a separate syntax checker) throw warnings whenever it meets a construct that looks like it may have a precedence error. We can even have several levels of verbosity and at the highest level have it ask for every construct that relies on a precedence rule whether the programmer meant to write that or the alternative. We can even have it insert brackets upon request.
This may be the best of both worlds: it allows the language to be permissive, while users and teams can still enforce non-permissive coding standards, even ones that completely eliminate all ambiguity.
